# How would I evaluate this? $\frac15\int_0^5(4+2^{0.1t^2})dt$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\frac15\int_0^5(4+2^{0.1t^2})dt$$
This question is from part (b) of question 1 in the AP Calculus BC 2019 FRQ. I've tried using u-substitution where $u = 0.1 t^2$, but this won't work because of the $2t$ that will result when taking the derivative of $u$. Integration by parts wouldn't work as the integral doesn't involve a product, and trigonometric substitution wouldn't work either. Is there a technique that would allow me to evaluate this?

Comment: Are you ok with using some special functions? Concretely the erfi$(x)$ function definitely helps here.

Comment: Perhaps the expectation was to solve it numerically because usual methods won't help in solving this integral.

Comment: I realized now that the question is supposed to be solved with a graphing calculator. I am not familiar with the erfi(x) function, I'll try and see what it is.

Comment: If you give me some minutes I can post an answer using the erfi$(x)$ function. Only if you want. However, it makes sense that you were supposed to do it using a graphical or numerical method anyway.

Comment: Sure! I think erfi is beyond what I'm supposed to have learned anyways but it's a good thing to know.

Comment: Ok, give a minute. Its a fun integral anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the term $2^{0.1 t^2} = e^{0.1\ln(2)t^2}$. It is well known that this type of exponential functions does not have an anti-derivative using elementary functions (polynomials, logarithms, exponentials, trigonometric functions). However, (definite) integrals for functions of this form can still be computed using a couple of special functions (which are at the end computed numerically).

Lets start this journey with the Gaussian function $e^{-t^2}$ which does not have an anti-derivative in elementary functions. However, the erf$(x)$ function is a special function which acts as its anti-derivative, defined (not very surprisingly) as:
$$
\text{erf}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^ze^{-t^2}\text{d}t
$$
However, note that in your case $e^{0.1\ln(2)t^2}$, the exponent is not negative: $0.1\ln(2)$>0. Thus, the erf$(z)$ function cannot be used direcly.

But! we can use a trick: the erfi$(z)$ function can be of use here and its defined as $\frac{1}{i}\text{erf}(iz)$ where $i^2=-1$. This is useful since
$$
\frac{1}{i}\text{erf}(iz) = \frac{2}{i\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{iz}e^{-t^2} \text{d}t = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^ze^{u^2}\text{d}u
$$
using a simple $u=t/i$ substitution. Hence, we can proceed to compute your original integral as:
$$
\int_0^5  e^{0.1\ln(2)t^2} \text{d}t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{0.1\ln(2)}}\int_0^{5\sqrt{0.1\ln(2)}}e^{u^2}\text{d}u
$$
using a simple $u = \left(\sqrt{0.1\ln(2)}\right) t$ substitution. Now,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{0.1\ln(2)}}\int_0^{5\sqrt{0.1\ln(2)}}e^{u^2}\text{d}u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{0.1\ln(2)}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{erfi}\left(5\sqrt{0.1\ln(2)}\right)\right)
$$
Thus,
$$
\int_0^52^{0.1 t^2}\text{d}t = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{0.1\ln(2)}}\text{erfi}\left(5\sqrt{0.1\ln(2)}\right)
$$

You can corroborate this result [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%202%5E%280.1*x%5E2%29%20from%200%20to%205%20) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28pi%2F%28ln%282%29*0.1%29%29%2F2*erfi%285*sqrt%28ln%282%29*0.1%29%29).

Now, this seems like cheating since instead of computing the original integral, you used a special function, defined in terms of another integral! Still, the erf$(x)$ and erfi$(x)$ functions are very well studied by now, and efficient, good trailor-made methods exist now to compute them instead of approximating the integral with a generic numerical methods.

Comment: Ahhhh I see what you did there. So erf and erfi are for these specific types of integrals involving $e^{t^2}$?

Comment: Yes, their purpose is to study integrals of those type of exponential functions.

Comment: Alright, thanks! What if the power was greater than 2 though?

Comment: Well, there are other special functions. Actually for $e^{t^a}$ for $a$ some integer grater than 2 you can use the incomplete Gamma function (defined using another integral). For example: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+exp%28t%5E8%29

Comment: There is a whole world beyond elementary functions. There is this very simple introduction to some special functions by Robert Ghrist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXxRODsa7SA

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the video.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: Introduction was interesting, so I found a nice video by blackpenredpen on the error function. It's starting to make more sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Without using special functions.*

Let us focus on

$$\int 2^{\frac{t^2}{10}}\,dt=\int \exp\Bigg[\frac{\log (2)}{10} t^2  \Bigg]\,dt$$ and expand the integrand as a Taylor series around $t=0$. This gives
$$\exp\Bigg[\frac{\log (2)}{10} t^2  \Bigg]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{\log (2)}{10}\right)^n}{n!}t^{2n}$$
$$\int\exp\Bigg[\frac{\log (2)}{10} t^2  \Bigg]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{\log (2)}{10}\right)^n}{(2n+1) \,n!}t^{2n+1}$$
$$\int_0^5\exp\Bigg[\frac{\log (2)}{10} t^2  \Bigg]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{5^{n+1} \log^n(2)}{2^n\,(2 n+1)\, n!}$$ Compute the partial sums (from $n=0$ to $n=p$) and obtain
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \sum_{n=0}^p \\
 0 & 5.00000 \\
 1 & 7.88811 \\
 2 & 9.38953 \\
 3 & 10.0090 \\
 4 & 10.2177 \\
 5 & 10.2769 \\
 6 & 10.2914 \\
 7 & 10.2945 \\
 8 & 10.2951 \\
 9 & 10.2952
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the exact solution.

If you are lazy (this is not a sin !), make $\log(2)\sim \frac 7 {10}$